# Why do I get None in output in second line while using eval function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, eval

I am executing this line of code -

```python
print(eval("print(2 +3)"))
```

but this instead of giving output as 5 gives output-

```
5
None
```

Comment: Because `eval("print (2 +3)")` prints 5 and returns `None`, so `print(eval(...))` also prints `None`.

Comment: Because [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function that returns None.

Comment: Just the same as if you took out the `eval` and wrote `print(print(2+3))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are giving eval() within print().

```
eval("(2 +3)")
```

This will return 5 as the function eval returns the value 5 which gets printed using the print()

However,

```py
print(eval("print(2 +3)"))
```

Here inside the eval() you have used print(). So the inner print() prints the value 5 and the function eval() returns None as it has nothing to return. That None gets printed by the outer print()

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get eval of something like
`eval("2")`
you are actually going to get type int.

But trying to evaluate print expression gives you None type. Print will be executed but type of
`eval("print(2+3)")`
will be None.